# Refreshing auth token when call retrofit api with rxandroid

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have working retrofit api, which return observable on some data.

Api use auth token for access to server. When auth token expired I have error message about it (Observer call onError in subscriber).

```
public Observable<MyObject> getObjectObservable() {
    return mApi.getObject();
}
```

I can refresh token with observable too:

```
private Observable<AuthResult> restoreToken() {
    return mApi.restoreToken(new RestoreTokenBody(getRestoreToken()));
}
```

How implement next steps in getObjectObservable function:

- First try mApi.getObject()
- On Error refresh token
- After refreshing it call mApi.getObject() again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use operator `onErrorResumeNext` Something like this:

```
public Observable<MyObject> getObjectObservable() {
    return mApi.getObject()
            .onErrorResumeNext(restoreToken().flatMap(authResult ->  mApi.getObject()));
}
```